# Interactive Grid columns width

Tags: oracle-apex

How I can set Interactive Grid columns width using CSS or JavaScript? I tried to use inline CSS:

```
th, td {
    width: 100px;
}
```

it's not working, with JavaScript I tried to set style.width for all of th and td elements, but is also not working. I want to set different width for two columns, and make it responsive for all displays. Solution with Minimum Column Width property does not suit me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions:

```
var ig = apex.region("REGION_NAME").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");
ig.modelColumns.COLUMN_NAME_1.width = "50%";
ig.modelColumns.COLUMN_NAME_2.width = "50%";
```

and

```
apex.region("REGION_NAME").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("setColumnWidth", "COLUMN_NAME_1", 50);
apex.region("REGION_NAME").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("setColumnWidth", "COLUMN_NAME_2", 50);
```